# SQLite pagination in a dynamic table

Tags: c++, mysql, sqlite, pagination

I have an SQLite table that changes very often, many times per minute. It is easily thinkable as a table of torrents, where new torrents are appended to the end of the table, and old ones (completed) are removed from the beginning.

This is presenting a logical headache for me to implement pagination, where there could be 100s of torrents in the table, but the table is changing rapidly. I am writing this in C++, with a GUI written in Javascript/HTML. Here is my logic so far. I think I know what I need to do, but I don't know how.

---

**Given:**

- The UI will always ask for a list of rows based on the page #, not SQL Ids
- The UI will always set the number of rows per page (10 in this eg)
- The app will always return to the UI the # of pages and the current page

---

On initialization, the UI will ask for Page 1 of data, limited to 10 rows . The application logic then is as follows

1. Get the number of rows in the table. (100)
2. Get the number of pages in the table (100 / 10) = 10
3. Get the first 10 rows. This can be done many ways, such as simply using `LIMIT` set to 10

The application function I have available looks something like this

`GetDbRows( startId, limit );`

So the UI (currently) must know the row ID to start at. If this is a static table, this is easy. The application returns the last ID to the UI. But it is a dynamic table, so this ID is meaningless. The last ID could actually be gone by the time the next page is requested.

So, using application logic, how can I properly split the DB into pages, and ask for page 2, for example? Can I do this without having to literally get all row IDs and split them? Is there any SQL syntax to do this for me? Such as `GET id at page 3`

Comment: Will LIMIT followed by OFFSET do what you want eg SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20? See: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html  This would give you the 3rd page

Comment: Beautiful.. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Richard Critten

> Will LIMIT followed by OFFSET do what you want eg SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20? See: sqlite.org/lang_select.html This would give you the 3rd page

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6E7e.gif)

**LIMIT**

The LIMIT clause is used to place an upper bound on the number of rows returned by the entire SELECT statement.

In a compound SELECT, only the last or right-most simple SELECT may contain a LIMIT clause. In a compound SELECT, the LIMIT clause applies to the entire compound, not just the final SELECT. If the right-most simple SELECT is a VALUES clause then no LIMIT clause is allowed.

**OFFSET**

Instead of a separate OFFSET clause, the LIMIT clause may specify two scalar expressions separated by a comma. In this case, the first expression is used as the OFFSET expression and the second as the LIMIT expression. This is counter-intuitive, as when using the OFFSET clause the second of the two expressions is the OFFSET and the first the LIMIT. This reversal of the offset and limit is intentional - it maximizes compatibility with other SQL database systems. However, to avoid confusion, programmers are strongly encouraged to use the form of the LIMIT clause that uses the "OFFSET" keyword and avoid using a LIMIT clause with a comma-separated offset.